# Problemas de performance com Asp.Net Core 2.1?

Tags: api, desempenho, iis, entity-framework-core, asp-net-core

Tenho uma API escrita em Asp.Net Core 2.1 e estou com algum problema de desempenho, não estou conseguindo entender se o problema é no código ou no servidor.

O problema se resume no seguinte, tenho um update simples que apenas desativa um registro e grava um log. Porém quando a API está rodando a um tempo no servidor de produção, está chamada começa a ficar cada vez mais lenta até começar dar failure. O uso de memória e processador do servidor estão sempre abaixo de 30%.
Configurei alguns recycles no IIS e ativei o ResponseCompression porém o problema persiste.

Segue os códigos do Startup e de um dos métodos que estão com o problema.

Startup.cs :

```
using System;
using SPTC.SISPLAN.API.WebSockets;
using SPTC.WebSockets;
using SPTC.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SPTC.SISPLAN.Service.Interfaces;
using SPTC.SISPLAN.Service;
using SPTC.SISPLAN.Service.Listas;
using SPTC.SISPLAN.Service.Interfaces.Listas;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using SPTC.SISPLAN.Service.Validation;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using IHostingEnvironment = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment;
using SPTC.SISPLAN.API.HostedServices;

namespace SPTC.SISPLAN.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<SPTCContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(s =>
            {
                s.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Info
                {
                    Version = "v2",
                    Title = "SISPLAN API",
                    Description = "Documentação de API do sistema SPTC-SISPLAN",
                });
                s.EnableAnnotations();
            });

            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.EnableForHttps = true;
            });


            services.AddCors();
            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.AddTransient<IAcaoService, AcaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IAcaoLogRevisaoAndamentoService, AcaoLogRevisaoAndamentoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IInstitutoService, InstitutoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IPerfilService, PerfilService>();
            services.AddTransient<IPreservacaoService, PreservacaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IStatusService, StatusService>();
            services.AddTransient<ITipoLocalService, TipoLocalService>();
            services.AddTransient<ITipoOperacaoService, TipoOperacaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<ITipoPendenciaService, TipoPendenciaService>();

            services.AddTransient<IAndamentoService, AndamentoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IDesignacaoService, DesignacaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<ILocalService, LocalService>();
            services.AddTransient<ILogAcessoUsuarioService, LogAcessoUsuarioService>();
            services.AddTransient<ILogRevisaoAndamentoService, LogRevisaoAndamentoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IOperacaoService, OperacaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IPendenciaService, PendenciaService>();
            services.AddTransient<IPermissaoService, PermissaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IPlantaoService, PlantaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IProtocoloService, ProtocoloService>();
            services.AddTransient<IRegiaoService, RegiaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<ITimeService, TimeService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUnidadeService, UnidadeService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUsuarioService, UsuarioService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUsuarioPlantaoService, UsuarioPlantaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IVitimaService, VitimaService>();
            services.AddTransient<IConfiguracaoService, ConfiguracaoService>();
            services.AddTransient<IEmergenciaService, EmergenciaService>();
            services.AddTransient<ITelefonesUteisService, TelefonesUteisService>();
            services.AddTransient<IHostedService, ReloadProtocolosTask>();
            services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddTransient<AuthenticatedUser>();

            services.AddWebSocketManager();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0),
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "testeIssuer",
                        ValidAudience = "testeAudience",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["SecurityKey"]))
                    };
                });

            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddJsonOptions(opts =>
            {
                opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new LowercaseContractResolver();
                opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                opts.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });

            services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
            {
                options.Configuration =
                  Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConexaoRedis");
                options.InstanceName = "Sisplan";
            });

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
                {
                    s.SwaggerEndpoint("v2/swagger.json", "SISPLAN API");
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            var wsOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
            {
                KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                ReceiveBufferSize = 4 * 1024
            };

            app.UseWebSockets(wsOptions);
            app.MapWebSocketManager("/protocolos", serviceProvider.GetService<ProtocolosHandler>());
            app.MapWebSocketManager("/mapa", serviceProvider.GetService<MapaHandler>());
            app.MapWebSocketManager("/unidades", serviceProvider.GetService<UnidadesHandler>());

            app.UseCors(builder => { 
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin(); 
                builder.AllowAnyMethod(); 
                builder.AllowAnyHeader(); 
            });

            app.UseResponseCompression();

            app.UseMvc();

        }

    }

    public class LowercaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            return propertyName.ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }
}
```

Método :

```
[Route("Cancelar/{motivo}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Cancelar(Protocolo protocolo, string motivo)
{
    try
    {
        Protocolo _protocolo = _protocoloService
            .Search(p => p.ID == protocolo.ID, p => p.Include(d => d.Designacoes))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        _protocolo.Active = false;

        foreach (Designacao designacao in _protocolo.Designacoes)
        {
            designacao.Active = false;
            designacao.ID_Status = (int)ListaStatus.Cancelado;
        }

        Andamento andamento = new Andamento
        {
            ID_Acao = (int)Acoes.Cancelado,
            ID_Usuario = int.Parse(_user.ID),
            ID_Protocolo = protocolo.ID,
            Detalhes = motivo
        };

        await _protocoloService.Update(_protocolo);
        await _andamentoService.Create(andamento);

        await this.TriggerWebSocketAsync("web", _protocolo.ID);

        return Ok();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        new TemplateEmailLog().EnviarEmailLog(
                    _configuration.GetValue<String>("EmailLog"),
                    "Protocolos",
                    "Cancelar",
                    _user.ID,
                    protocolo,
                    e);
        return BadRequest("Ocorreu um erro ao cancelar o protocolo.");
    }

}
```

Vale citar que utilizei um StopWatch para medir o tempo de execução do search, update e create, e todos não chegam nem a 1 segundo mesmo quando a resposta começa a ficar mais demorada.

Quando o sistema para de responder de vez ocorre a seguinte exceção:

> Mensagem (Exception): The operation was canceled.
>
> Detalhes (Inner Exception): Cannot write to the response body, the
> response has completed. Object name: 'HttpResponseStream'.
>
> StackTrace: at
> System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.SendFrameFallbackAsync(MessageOpcode
> opcode, Boolean endOfMessage, ReadOnlyMemory`1 payloadBuffer,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> SPTC.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.SendMessageAsync(WebSocket socket,
> String message) in
> C:\Users\william.wos\Documents\ProjectSisplan\trunk\SPTC.WebSocket\SPTC.WebSocket\WebSocket\WebSocketHandler.cs:line
> 34 at SPTC.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.SendMessageAsync(String
> socketId, String message) in
> C:\Users\william.wos\Documents\ProjectSisplan\trunk\SPTC.WebSocket\SPTC.WebSocket\WebSocket\WebSocketHandler.cs:line
> 46 at SPTC.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.SendMessageToAllAsync(String
> message) in
> C:\Users\william.wos\Documents\ProjectSisplan\trunk\SPTC.WebSocket\SPTC.WebSocket\WebSocket\WebSocketHandler.cs:line
> 64 at
> SPTC.SISPLAN.API.WebSockets.UnidadesHandler.SendMessageToAllAsync(String
> sender, Object message, Action action) in
> Z:\Renner\Sistemas\Projetos\SISPLAN\branches\SPTC.SISPLAN.API\Fase02\SPTC.SISPLAN.API\WebSockets\UnidadesHandler.cs:line
> 25 at
> SPTC.SISPLAN.API.Controllers.ProtocolosController.TriggerWebSocketAsync(String
> origem, Int32 id_protocolo, Boolean recusadoFromDesignacao) in
> Z:\Renner\Sistemas\Projetos\SISPLAN\branches\SPTC.SISPLAN.API\Fase02\SPTC.SISPLAN.API\Controllers\ProtocolosController.cs:line
> 153 at
> SPTC.SISPLAN.API.Controllers.ProtocolosController.Cancelar(Protocolo
> protocolo, String motivo) in
> Z:\Renner\Sistemas\Projetos\SISPLAN\branches\SPTC.SISPLAN.API\Fase02\SPTC.SISPLAN.API\Controllers\ProtocolosController.cs:line
> 769

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Qual é a exceção que é gerada no servidor? Você poderia anexar um stack trace dela? Quanto tempo demora uma chamada HTTP POST Cancelar/{motivo}?

Comment: Uma chamada HTTP POST Cancelar/{motivo} caso esteja rodando normal leva 1 segundo com o erro chega a levar entre 40 segundos a mais de 2 minutos. Quando ele deixa de executar tem o stacktrace que vou editar acima.

Comment: Qual é a linha-> 769 do Controller ProtocolosController.cs:line?

Comment: await this.TriggerWebSocketAsync("web", _protocolo.ID);

Comment: Em algumas tentativas de execução nem chega a dar exceção, ai a resposta vem como 502 por conta do timeout

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente a exceção descrita no stack trace parece ser em erro de timeout na chamada do método `TriggerWebSocketAsync` causado por uma tentativa de escrever dados em um WebSocket cuja conexão foi encerrada de forma abrupta pelo cliente sem notificar o servidor. Para reproduzir esse problema, basta puxar o cabo de rede de um cliente que esteja conectado neste WebSocket.

Isso poderia ser resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await this.TriggerWebSocketAsync("web", _protocolo.ID);
});
```

Além disso, outro ponto de lentidão a ser observado é no método `EnviarEmailLog`. O ideal é que a sua aplicação não dependa de um serviço tão instável e relativamente lento quanto o envio de e-mails para poder gerar logs. Que por sua vez, pode gerar outras exceções.

Comment: Quanto ao email de log eu consigo remodelar, no websocket saberia me dar uma luz de como posso tratar esse caso da conexão encerrada?

Comment: @RennerOliveira, Resposta atualizada.

Comment: implementei do dessa maneira mas acontece que agora o websocket está disparando apenas na primeira chamada

Comment: Então era esse o problema, correto?

Comment: Na verdade não, ele melhorou um pouco o desempenho com essa implementação, mas ainda chega uma hora que começa a travar, fiz um teste de stress manual, e se eu fico repetindo as mesmas chamadas uma hora ele começa a demorar pra responder, mesmo com o mesmo tanto de conexões abertas no websocket